# Sources for simple probability brain teasers

Tags: probability, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am searching for a book that can supply me with probability brain teasers, that can be solved using little arithmetic/mental math, paired with somewhat detailed solutions. Any suggestions?

Basically I am trying to work on my ability to solve simple probability problems and all the books I have been finding are intro to probability textbooks etc. What would be ideal is  a "probability question of the day" book or even a website that supplies that. I want practice not a lesson book.

Thanks.

Example:
`A cube painted with red paint was divided into 27 smaller cubes (3*3*3). Randomly pick one and toss it. What is the probability that at least one of the sides that can be seen has paint on it?`

Comment: A lesson book is full of practice. Practice often leads to a lesson book.

Comment: I've always liked Mosteller's book, 50 Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions.  Published by Dover.

Comment: @ConradoCosta I'm saying that I would like a book of questions or exercises rather than text to read. Thanks.

Comment: you could ask for simple beautiful problems as the one you wrote in your example. I have one in mind, I am sure a big list would help you collect many charming examples.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I'll take a look, that's exactly what I am looking for!